# Collection Filtering using Field in Mongo DB in Meteor?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I need to know about filters using mongo collections using collection fields in meteor.

In my collection there are 3 fields in total:

1. Name
2. Staff Yes/No
3. Qualification B.tech/M.tech

How to Filter using Staff either selects 'Yes' or 'No' and 'All'?

If selects 'Yes' then only get results from collection in staff field using 'Yes'?

I didn't get any idea about this.So please suggest me what do for this?

Code :

```
getStaffYesResult: function getStaffYesResult(callback){    
    console.log('********* getStaffYesResult ************** ');

    var filterResult = auth_user.findOne({is_staff:1});//Here get all records is staff true indicates 1 in collection.

    console.log('filterResult Length : ' + filterResult.length);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use collection.find.

See the official documentation at: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/find

An example would be:

```
var find = Person.find({staff: true});
```

Comment: how to get all true records using staff field in meteor?.@Alveoli

Comment: if you post your collection definition code we would be able to provide a more precise answer...

Comment: Can you please check above post once.@Alveoli

Comment: Use find() not findOne().  FindOne will only return the first result, not all the results - I'll amend my answer

Comment: How can i select sometimes not checking staff and some times checking staff and qualification means staff - all(no checking true/false) and checking qualification like inner filters type in single query?.@Alveoli